# Which OpenJDK distribution does Docker use?

Tags: java, docker

As I understood it, "OpenJDK" is just the mercurial repository (http://hg.openjdk.java.net).

It needs somebody (Oracle, RedHat, AdoptOpenJDK, Amazon's Corretto, etc.) to build and package it up into an "OpenJDK distribution".

So, my question is: when I do:

```
docker pull openjdk
```

Whose distribution am I getting?

It seems important, as each of the distributions I listed above have different policies around how they deal with security patches, etc.

Or have I missed something here?

Comment: If unsure, build your own docker image for distribution you are familiar with.

Comment: You should probably specify the distro in the tag when you pull instead of leaving it ambiguous. That would remove the uncertainty here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the dockerfile for reveals it is Debian: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/11/jdk/buster/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the default configuration , when you run

```
docker pull openjdk
```

You are pulling the images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/)

Which pulls the following image : https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

The source of this image can be found at https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/

Answer (score 0):

*"Whose distribution am I getting?"*

If you are pulling the image from, say, Dockerhub, there are two ways to interpret your question.

1. What OS version is the image based on?
2. Who created the image?

The answer to the second question requires you to do some digging in the commit history of the Docker file. If you care about such things you'd really be better off downloading the Docker file and building the image locally.

As to the first question, the answer depends on the image tag you are using so for example the the image tagged as tag "12:alpine" is based on alpine:3.8   (see here for more https://hub.docker.com/r/library/openjdk/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 11-oracle tag to pull Oracle OpenJDK 11 releases.

```
docker pull openjdk:11-oracle
```

pulls the latest one.

You can also use the 12-ea tag to pull Oracle OpenJDK 12 Early Access builds, i.e.

```
docker pull openjdk:12-ea
```

Answer (score 0):

when you don't specify the tag. It chooses the default tag set at the repository as indicated by :

```
Using default tag: latest
```

So it all depends on which image is tagged same as the latest (using docker tag command or equivalent - it's like symbolic link) that's the one you'll get.